# How to extract multiple prices (ex: "$46.99") from a string <?PHP ?>

Tags: php, string, curl, int, bots

Input: `string = "10 New from $9.00 40 Used from $0.74";`

Desired output: `$new = 9.00; $used = 0.74;`

I pulled the prices of a book from the source code of a website via cURL, and need to extract the highest ($new_price), and lowest ($used_price) from a segment of the code.
Hello,
I know this sounds like a very easy issue to get by, but I have put about 5 hours into trying to figure it out and have turned up with nothing. My goal is to remove two prices from a string of source code (gathered by cURL) and store each in its own variable. The problems I keep running into is that I do not know how many digits the price will be (one to four digits), and for some reason I cannot use the function substr(). My only guess is that maybe the "string" I am counting isn't a string at all, but some other data type as it is a section of HTML. 
Here is what I've tried so far:

Attempt 1: Removed all characters != numbers. I was left with the two numbers, but could not figure out how to separate the two decimals into variables.

Attempt 2: Tried splitting entire string into two pieces, each containing an integer that I could isolate. The problem I ran into was I could not count the string to separate it with substr(). Also, there would have been more than one number in each string, so I would have had to only recognize ints beginning with "$"

Comment: I'm sure a regex similar to `\$(\d.\d+)` would suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd best use regex to achieve what you want (Using this regex `/\$(\d.\d+)`).

```
$string = "10 New from $9.00 40 Used from $0.74";
preg_match_all('/\$(\d\.\d+)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Which returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $9.00
            [1] => $0.74
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9.00
            [1] => 0.74
        )

)
```

Allowing you to assign the values as you choose from the first index.

```
$new = $matches[0][0];
$used = $matches[0][1];
```

Or you could loop through and do as you please.

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/292510)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, which if you are unfamiliar, is whole other discussion.

Here's a snippet that you might be able to use though. I made this up kind of quickly, so it might not work in all cases, but it should be a start.

```
<?php

$string = "10 New from $9.00 40 Used from $0.74";

$pattern = '/^(.*)(New(.*)(?P<new>\$[0-9]+\.[0-9]+))(.*)(Used(.*)(?P<used>\$[0-9]+\.[0-9]+))(.*)$/i';

if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
  $new = $matches['new'];
  $used = $matches['used'];

  echo "New: $new...\n";
  echo "Used: $used...\n";
}
else {
  echo "No prices found in string...\n";
}

?>
```